# How to output the time difference in hours and minutes between to timestamps

Tags: php, date, datetime

I need to get hours and minutes difference between two timestamps, but the following code outputs only hours.

Expected output:

```
2:30 hours
```

but it outputs:

```
2
```

The code I am using:

```
echo -(date("H:i", strtotime("04:30AM")) - date("H:i", strtotime("07:00AM")));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DateInterval`:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('04:30AM');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('07:00AM');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%h:%i'); // 2:30
```

[datetime.diff](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)
[dateinterval.format](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

Comment: But it doesn't calcualte from PM to AM. If `$from="09.00PM" $to="01.00AM"` it outputs, `20:00 hrs` but it should output  `04:00 hrs` . As it calculates from AM to PM I don't get correct output

Comment: It's because both relates to `today`, it returns "-20:00". You can get a sign with `%R`

Comment: Also, `(new DateTime('09:00PM'))->diff(new DateTime('01:00AM +1day'))->format('%R%H:%I');` gets `+04:00`

Comment: Thank you so much!